# Doctrine foreign keys

Tags: php, doctrine

I get table -

```
$data = Doctrine::getTable('product_catalog')->findAll();
```

this table (product_catalog) i link table. has 2 columns with foreign keys.

how i can check if `$data` has a relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded in getting relation from table:

```
$data = ORM::getTable($modelName)->findAll(); - get the table.
$relations = $data->getTable()->getRelations();  - >get to relation
foreach($relations as $key=>$row)
   {
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($key); echo "</pre>"; 


   }
 die();
```

This will print the table relation on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$data->hasRelation('RelationName')` which will check for the existence of the related object on your foreign key. Replace `RelationName` with the real name of your relation.

Comment: in version 2.0 the function 'hasRelation' was not exists.maybe have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with Doctrine 2:

```
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(YOUR_DQL_QUERY);
    $query->setHint(Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
    $query->getArrayResult();
```